# listのi番目の要素をlistに入れる方法

Tags: python, python3

list1と2がある場合について考えます

```
import itertools

l = [0,1,2,3]
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  for v in itertools.permutations(l):
    print(v, file=f)
with open('file.txt') as f:
  datalist = f.readlines()
```

list1には0,1,2,3の数字から３つ選ぶ順列の結果が要素として(1,2,3)のように含まれています。
list2にこの数字を入れてlist2 = [1,2,3]にしたいです。しかし、下記のコードを実行すると'('や' '(空白)なども要素の一つとしてカウントされていまします。数字のみを要素として入れる方法はありますか？

```
list2 = list1[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import itertools
from ast import literal_eval

l = [0,1,2,3]
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  for v in itertools.permutations(l, 3):
    print(v, file=f)

with open('file.txt') as f:
    list1 = [list(literal_eval(line)) for line in f]

i = 9
list2 = list1[i]
print(list2)

# [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

たぶんこういうことかなと
(listの listということだけど, tupleで, でもアクセス方法は同じ)

```py
import itertools
l = [0,1,2,3]
list2 = [v for v in itertools.permutations(l, 3)]

print(f'{list2[9]=}')
# list2[9]=(1, 2, 3)

print(f'{list2[9][2]=}')
# list2[9][2]=3
```